# Linked list with square brackets

Tags: arrays, c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to understand singly linked lists and structs in C. I would appreciate an explanation of what this bit of code does, and in particular what the square brackets and `.` mean.

```
void initialize_new_line(t_parser_state *state)
{
    state->position = 0;
    state->break_position = 0;
    state->cur_node = NULL;
    state->lines[state->line_number].nodes = NULL;
    state->lines[state->line_number].search = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Guessing from the context: `state->lines` is likely an array, `state->line_number` is likely an int used as index. I have an array, I have an index - uh! I have an `array[index]`.

Comment: Before you start understanding basics of linked lists in C you definitely need to start understanding basics of C. There's no way to read or write in any language (including C) before you learn basic vocabulary and basic grammar of the language.

Comment: `[ ]` is array indexing. Not to be rude but.... If you don't know about C arrays yet, it's too early to learn about linked lists and structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From top to bottom:

```
void initialize_new_line(t_parser_state *state)
```

This declares a function called "initialize_new_line", which takes one parameter called "state" which is of the type "pointer to the type `t_parser_state`". This function does not return anything (it returns "void"). The function definition follows and consists of assignments only.

```
state->position = 0;
state->break_position = 0;
state->cur_node = NULL;
```

The [member access through pointer operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) `->` indicates that the type `t_parser_state` is a struct. The members `position` and `break_position` have some kind of integral type as these are initialized with a 0 integer constant, but we cannot say with certainty which one. Similarly, the member `cur_node` is a pointer, but to what type cannot be inferred.

```
state->lines[state->line_number].nodes = NULL;
state->lines[state->line_number].search = NULL;
```

The [array subscript operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) (`[]`) indicate that `lines` must be an array. The member `line_number` must be some kind of integer type, as it is used an an index to the array. The [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) (`.`) indicates that the elements of `lines` must have the type struct or the type union, having the members `nodes` and `search`. Since *both* are set to `NULL`, we may assume that the element type is `struct`. The array members `nodes` and `search` are pointers to some unknown type, as these are set to the null pointer constant.